# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure PROC_T

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
declare
    TYPE stag_tab IS TABLE OF d_staging%ROWTYPE;
    stag_tab1 stag_tab; 
begin
    --Bulk Collect
    select * bulk collect into staging_tab1 from d_staging; 
    PKG_T.PROC_T(stag_tab1);
end;
/
```

### Package definition:

```
--Package 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_T 
AS 
  TYPE staging IS TABLE OF d_staging%ROWTYPE; 
  PROCEDURE PROC_T(p_staging IN staging); 
END PKG_T; 
/

-- Package Body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_T
AS
  PROCEDURE PROC_T (p_staging IN staging) 
  AS 
     VAR1 d_staging%ROWTYPE; 
     CUR1 SYS_REFCURSOR; 
     QUERY_STRING VARCHAR2(2000); 
  BEGIN 
    OPEN CUR1 FOR SELECT * from table(p_staging); 
    LOOP 
      FETCH CUR1 into VAR1; 
      EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND; 
      INSERT into d (testdata) VALUES (var1.testval1); 
      COMMIT; 
    END LOOP; 
  END; 
END PKG_T;
/
```

Comment: Could you put the definition of `PKG_T.PROC_T` as well ? and why into `into staging_tab1` but the variable declared is `stag_tab1` ?

Comment: PROCEDURE PROC_T
                    (p_staging IN staging)
           AS
            VAR1 d_staging%ROWTYPE;
            CUR1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
            QUERY_STRING VARCHAR2(2000);
           BEGIN
                OPEN CUR1 FOR 
                SELECT * from table(p_staging);
                loop
                fetch CUR1 into VAR1;
                EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
                insert into d (testdata)
                values (var1.testval1) ;
                commit;
                end loop;
           END;
        END PKG_T;    
        /

Comment: @EJEgyed Not able to add in  question so added in comment

Comment: I added to the question and you can delete the comment now

Comment: Thanks @Sujitmohanty30

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the error because the procedure `PKG_T.PROC_T` is expecting a parameter of type `staging`, but when you are calling the procedure you are passing it a variable of type `stag_tab`. The type of the variable being passed to the procedure needs to match the type of the parameter definition for the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure declaration:

```sql
PROCEDURE PROC_T (p_staging IN staging)
```

Takes the argument as type `staging`.

You are passing the argument as a locally defined type:

```sql
TYPE stag_tab IS TABLE OF d_staging%ROWTYPE;
```

These are different types. Instead, you need the PL/SQL block to be:

```sql
declare
    stag_tab1 package_name.staging; 
begin
    select *
    bulk collect into stag_tab1
    from d_staging; 

    PKG_T.PROC_T(stag_tab1);
end;
/
```

Comment: @Vikash Kumar Sharma, You always can accept the answer if it resolved your problem